# how to get data from previous page to next page ,get id using PDO by $_GET METHOD

Tags: php, pdo

*here my code called data.php*

```
<?php 
sql = db->query('SELECT* FROM tb_karyawan order by kar_id desc');
while($data = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
} ?>
```

> nilai.php?hal=tambah&kd=

*and my nilai.php*

```
<?php
$sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM tb_karyawan WHERE kar_id=$_GET["kar_id"]) .');
$data = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

*how to get kar_id from previous page to next page by $_GET METHOD using PDO  i am new for PDO 
THANKS*

Comment: You're already using PDO, **please please please PLEASE** bind your parameters instead of passing it through as you are. Save yourself from SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
while($data = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
    <a href="nilai.php?kar_id='<?php echo $data['kar_id'] ?>'">Link</a>
<?php }
?>
```

nilai.php:

```
$kar_id = $_GET["kar_id"];
$sql = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tb_karyawan WHERE kar_id=:kar_id');
$sql->bindValue(':kar_id', $kar_id , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->execute();
```

Comment: `query` doesn't take placeholders.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function bindValue() on boolean in nilai.php , any suggestion ? thanks

Comment: remove space form here and try once $sql ->bindValue

Comment: same nothing happen , still Fatal error

Comment: $sql = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tb_karyawan WHERE kar_id=:kar_id'); try this check out updated code

Comment: thanks it works , may i ask  1 more thing , how i fecth my data based by id ? i have try but not luck ,

Comment: same as above query you have to pass condition like where id =  '?'

Comment: For simple queries with just a few params, I just use positional placeholders like this

     $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND status = ?');
     $stmt->execute([$username, $status]);
     $user = $stmt->fetch();